# Pidgin connects to Facebook chat but not to GTalk wiht Tor. How can that be?

Tags: port, pidgin, tor, google-talk, facebook-chat

I am using Pidgin on Ubuntu 12.04. The university network blocks (I think) port 5222 for XMMP connections. I thought about using Tor to circumvent that. I installed Tor and configured pidgin to use it. Facebook connects fine but gtalk says "unable to connect". Any idea what is wrong? The configuration is otherwise good, I know it works onother networks.

Do you know about any other means to circumvent blocking of port 5222 for accessing gtalk?

Comment: (I have solved the issue in other way ( http://superuser.com/questions/508334/how-to-connect-with-pidgin-to-facebook-chat-and-google-talk-when-xmpp-port-5222/508335#508335 ), but still have no idea why google talk did not work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am on 12.10 (not sure if it is related) but there is a Tor option in the proxy settings for each individual account and that actually works. (only you get an e-mail from google that somebody is trying to break into your account but you can override that. Facebook does the same, but helpfully sends you an IM message instead of an e-mail)